# Is there a way to not show windows user log on screen when admin is remotely connected to system

Tags: windows, rdp

i want to connect to my system using RDP connection - I am seeing the windows user log on screen on my tablet / monitor which has options like Ease of access shutdown etc i do not want this to show on the tablet . I would like a screen saver to be displayed or a logo screen to be displayed on the tablet/ monitor as soon as i connect via RDP

I have tried tscon & Rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation nothing works for me 
Also after my RDP session is closed I want to be able to resume my standard user session without me typing password

Comment: this is more suited for www.superuser.com stackoverflow is for programming related question

Comment: thanks have posted on that